# Bash scripting arguments

Tags: bash, arguments

I am currently taking a linux class.  I pretty much have to learn stuff on my own.  I have writtent this script to produce a date format based on the argument.  Ie (./script.sh one).  I am having an issue getting this script to do just that.  I think that i have something wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ $1="one" ]
    then
        date +%m-%d-%y 

elif [ $2="two" ]
    then
        date +%d-%m-%y

elif [ $3="three" ]
    then
        date +%A,%B-%d,%Y 

elif [ $4="four" ]
    then
        date +%s 
elif [ $5="five" ]
    then

fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Shell scripts are counter-intuitively whitespace-sensitive. There must be spaces before and after the equal signs. You also can't have a completely empty `if` statement. There must be at least one statement in there. If you don't have anything, writing `:` is the common idiom for a null statement.

```
if [ $1 = "one" ]; then
    date +%m-%d-%y 
elif [ $2 = "two" ]; then
    date +%d-%m-%y
elif [ $3 = "three" ]; then
    date +%A,%B-%d,%Y 
elif [ $4 = "four" ]; then
    date +%s 
elif [ $5 = "five" ]; then
    :
fi
```

I am guessing you might also want to use `$1` in all of the checks, not `$1` through `$5`—i.e., check what the first argument is. If that's true then you could swap the `if`s for a `case`.

```
case $1 in
    one)   date +%m-%d-%y;;
    two)   date +%d-%m-%y;;
    three) date +%A,%B-%d,%Y;;
    four)  date +%s;;
    five)  ;;
esac
```

Comment: John, thanks so much for the help.  Just another question; I thought that the "fi" ended the script, so why doe i have to put the : before the "fi".  I guess im not sure why i need to create a null statement before the "fi".

Comment: @JamesCook The `:` stands in for the missing `date` command. `:` is a command which does nothing. You need to have a command after a `then`, you can't have `then` followed immediately by `fi`; it's a syntactical requirement.

Comment: The bottom script is so much easier! thank you so much for your help John.